# Turn on Xperia automatically when the charger is connected

Tags: android, sony-xperia

I'm trying to repurposed my Sony Xperia Z3 Compact into a lcd display project. In order to proceed, I would like to mod my Xperia phone so that the phone will automatically turn on when charger turn ON. I search around and found some script like https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected  and some people mentioned that I should mod chargemon file. But when I replace this file, my phone cannot boot into the system.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

While checking the file, I notice that there 2 file chargemon and another is chargemon.stock. attached here [chargemonfile](http://www.mediafire.com/file/ld5o6lilyuykxbp/chargemon.zip/file) . Actually this file have been edited during rooting process which I get it from xda forum https://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/general/recovery-root-mm-575-lb-t3418714

```
#!/system/xbin/busybox sh

BUSYBOX=/system/xbin/busybox

VIB=/sys/class/timed_output/vibrator/enable
R_LED=/sys/class/leds/led:rgb_red/brightness
G_LED=/sys/class/leds/led:rgb_green/brightness
B_LED=/sys/class/leds/led:rgb_blue/brightness

LOG="/cache/mm_twrp_recovery.log"
WORKDIR="/cache/mm_twrp_recovery_keycheck"

MKDIR="${BUSYBOX} mkdir"
CHOWN="${BUSYBOX} chown"
CHMOD="${BUSYBOX} chmod"
TOUCH="${BUSYBOX} touch"
CAT="${BUSYBOX} cat"
SLEEP="${BUSYBOX} sleep"
KILL="${BUSYBOX} kill"
RM="${BUSYBOX} rm"
PS="${BUSYBOX} ps"
GREP="${BUSYBOX} grep"
AWK="${BUSYBOX} awk"
EXPR="${BUSYBOX} expr"
MOUNT="${BUSYBOX} mount"
LS="${BUSYBOX} ls"
HEXDUMP="${BUSYBOX} hexdump"
CP="${BUSYBOX} cp"

${RM} -f ${LOG}
echo "chargemon" >> ${LOG}

BOOTTWRP=0

if [ -e "/cache/recovery/boot" ]; then

    echo "  /cache/recovery/boot file found" >> ${LOG}
    
    ${RM} -f /cache/recovery/boot
    
    echo 255 > ${R_LED}
    echo 0 > ${G_LED}
    echo 255 > ${B_LED}
    
    BOOTTWRP=1

else

    if [ ! -d "${WORKDIR}" ]; then
        
        ${MKDIR} ${WORKDIR}
        ${CHOWN} system.cache ${WORKDIR}
        ${CHMOD} 770 ${WORKDIR}
        
    fi

    if [ ! -e ${WORKDIR}/keycheck ]; then
        
        ${RM} ${WORKDIR}/keyevent*
        ${RM} ${WORKDIR}/keycheck_down
        ${RM} ${WORKDIR}/ps*
        
    fi
    
    echo 0 > ${R_LED}
    echo 255 > ${G_LED}
    echo 0 > ${B_LED}
    
    echo 150 > ${VIB}
    
    for EVENTDEV in $(${LS} /dev/input/event* ); do
    
        SUFFIX="$(${EXPR} ${EVENTDEV} : '/dev/input/event\(.*\)')"
        ${CAT} ${EVENTDEV} > ${WORKDIR}/keyevent${SUFFIX} &
        
    done
    
    ${SLEEP} 2

    ${PS} > ${WORKDIR}/ps.log
    ${CHMOD} 660 ${WORKDIR}/ps.log

    for CATPROC in $(${PS} | ${GREP} /dev/input/event | ${GREP} -v grep | ${AWK} '{print $1}'); do
    
        ${KILL} -9 ${CATPROC}
       
    done
    
    ${HEXDUMP} ${WORKDIR}/keyevent* | ${GREP} -e '^.* 0001 0072 .... ....$' > ${WORKDIR}/keycheck_down

    if [ -s ${WORKDIR}/keycheck_down ]; then

        echo "  keycheck volume down - ok" >> ${LOG}
    
        echo 255 > ${R_LED}
        echo 0 > ${G_LED}
        echo 255 > ${B_LED}
        
        BOOTTWRP=1

    fi
    
fi

if [ $BOOTTWRP -eq 1 ]; then

    echo "  remount rootfs rw" >> ${LOG}
    mount -o remount,rw rootfs / 2>> ${LOG}
    
    echo "  copy busybox to /sbin" >> ${LOG}
    ${CP} /system/etc/mm_twrp_recovery/busybox /sbin
    ${CHOWN} 0.2000 /sbin/busybox
    ${CHMOD} 755 /sbin/busybox
    
    BUSYBOX=/sbin/busybox
    
    echo "  copy boot_twrp_recovery.sh to /sbin" >> ${LOG}
    ${CP} /system/etc/mm_twrp_recovery/boot_twrp_recovery.sh /sbin
    ${CHOWN} 0.0 /sbin/boot_twrp_recovery.sh
    ${CHMOD} 755 /sbin/boot_twrp_recovery.sh

    echo "  copy recovery.twrp.cpio.lzma to /sbin" >> ${LOG}
    ${CP} /system/etc/mm_twrp_recovery/recovery.twrp.cpio.lzma /sbin
    ${CHOWN} 0.0 /sbin/recovery.twrp.cpio.lzma
    ${CHMOD} 644 /sbin/recovery.twrp.cpio.lzma
    
    echo "  unpack recovery.twrp.cpio.lzma" >> ${LOG}
    ${BUSYBOX} lzma -d /sbin/recovery.twrp.cpio.lzma
    
    echo "  exec boot_twrp_recovery.sh (twrp boot)" >> ${LOG}
    exec /sbin/boot_twrp_recovery.sh

fi

echo 0 > ${B_LED}
echo 0 > ${R_LED}
echo 0 > ${G_LED}

echo "  exec chargemon.stock (regular boot)" >> ${LOG}
exec /system/bin/chargemon.stock
exit 0
```

So im thinking, I shouldn't replace this file entirely but just add another line of code. Now, if anyone have experience regarding this maybe can share some input or help me modify the existing script.

My main goal is to get my xperia phone turn on when im plugin the charger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by comment out this line `exec /system/bin/chargemon.stock`

Ref: https://z4-forum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=56746&start=90